# Upload Website to GitHub

Tags: github

I have a website project with several folders and sub folders on my desktop. I would like to copy this website to GitHub. What is the best way doing so when using the GitHub desktop app? It seems like I can only upload individual files but no folders.

Comment: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 0):

Open up your ssh and type in the following:

```
cd [full project folder name] (eg ~/desktop/project1)
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:[YourUSERNAME]/[YourREPOSITORY].git 
git push -u origin master
```

Step 5 could be replaced with:

```
git remote add origin [Your HTTPS repository]
```

If you get errors requesting ssh keys. (although you should set them up if possible.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyDwh.png

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

USING Command line:

```
1. Create repo in github
2. Click clone or download then copy the URL
3. In command line,Navigate to the root of your project folder
4. initialize: git init
5. track files: git add . 
6. commit: git commit -m "your message/comment"
7. add remote repository: git remote add origin 'paste the repo link'
8. git push origin master
```

USING APP.

```
1. Create Repo on Github site
2. On you app, click + sign, under clone tab and Find that repo, then clone
3. Put all your files/folders inside 
4. Then Sync
```